# Angular NgRX - effect is not being called from dispatched action

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Thee are many posts on this, but I cannot see what is wrong in my simple case (I am a rather new to NgRx, so could be a simple mistake).

I have been putting together as simple a example as I can to help with another issue I am having, but I can't get my the example working, and I just cannot see what is wrong here.

The example is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-polling2).

When you click the Start polling button, the action `startPolling` is dispatched, but the effect in `app.effects.ts`...

```
     public startPolling$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(appActions.startPolling),    
      tap(_ => console.log('app effect started polling')),  
      tap(() => this.isPollingActive = true),        
      mergeMap(() =>
        this.appDataSurvice.getData()
          .pipe(                        
            switchMap(data => {              
              return [appActions.getDataSuccess(data)
              ];
              }),
            catchError(err => of(appActions.getDataFail(err)))
          ))
    ));
```

Is just not being called, ie I never see the "app effect started polling" console log. What might I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem...

forgot the `EffectsModule.forRoot([AppEffects])` in app.module.ts